# OpenLDAP Centos 7 LDAP server request for passphrase

Tags: linux, centos, openldap

I'm trying to setup OpenLDAP running with TLS (2.4.39 and Centos 7).  When client sends a ldapsearch requests, somehow the server prompts for a passphrase/password.  See below when running 'slapd' output (asking for password at the end).  I must have done something wrong when setting up the Mozilla nss ceritificate?

```
# slapd -u ldap -h ldaps:// -d -1
...
55305109 slapd startup: initiated.
55305109 backend_startup_one: starting "cn=config"
55305109 config_back_db_open
Backend ACL: access to *
    by * none

55305109 config_back_db_open: line 0: warning: cannot assess the validity of the ACL scope within backend naming context
55305109 backend_startup_one: starting "dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com"
55305109 bdb_db_open: "dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com"
55305109 bdb_db_open: database "dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com": dbenv_open(/var/lib/ldap/xxxxxxx.com).
55305109 bdb_monitor_db_open: monitoring disabled; configure monitor database to enable
55305109 slapd starting
55305109 daemon: added 4r listener=(nil)
55305109 daemon: added 7r listener=0x7fb461bbd430
55305109 daemon: added 8r listener=0x7fb461bbd530
55305109 daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
55305109 daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
55305109 daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
55305109 daemon: activity on:55305109 
55305109 daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
55305109 daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
55305156 daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
55305156 daemon: activity on:55305156 
55305156 slap_listener_activate(7): 
55305156 daemon: epoll: listen=7 busy
55305156 daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
55305156 >>> slap_listener(ldaps://)
55305156 daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
55305156 daemon: activity on:55305156 
55305156 daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
55305156 daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
55305156 daemon: listen=7, new connection on 15
55305156 daemon: added 15r (active) listener=(nil)
55305156 conn=1000 fd=15 ACCEPT from IP=10.42.0.215:50115 (IP=0.0.0.0:636)
55305156 daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
55305156 daemon: activity on:55305156 
55305156 daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
55305156 daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
55305156 daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
55305156 daemon: activity on:55305156  15r55305156 
55305156 daemon: read active on 15
55305156 daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
55305156 daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
55305156 connection_get(15)
55305156 connection_get(15): got connid=1000
55305156 connection_read(15): checking for input on id=1000
TLS: certdb config: configDir='/etc/openldap/certs' tokenDescription='ldap(0)' certPrefix='' keyPrefix='' flags=readOnly
TLS: using moznss security dir /etc/openldap/certs prefix .
TLS: certificate 'Server-Cert' successfully loaded from moznss database.
TLS: no unlocked certificate for certificate 'CN=ldapserver.xxxxxxx.com'.
Please enter pin, password, or pass phrase for security token 'ldap(0)': 
TLS: certificate [CN=ldapserver.xxxxxxx.com] is valid
tls_read: want=3, got=3
  0000:  16 03 01                                           ...               
tls_read: want=2, got=2
  0000:  00 ae                                                ..                
tls_read: want=174, got=174
```

...

This is the certificate were generated:

```
# cd /etc/openldap/certs
# echo 12345 > password
# certutil -N -d . -f password 
# certutil -S -n "CA certificate" -s "cn=CAcert, dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com" -2 -x -t "CT,," -m 1000 -v 120 -d . -k rsa -f password 
# certutil -S -n "Server-Cert" -s "cn=ldapserver.xxxxxxx.com" -c "CA certificate" -t "u,u,u" -m 1001 -v 120 -d . -k rsa -f password

# # export the certificate for client
# stored in client machine /etc/openldap/certs/
# certutil -d . -L -n "CA certificate" -a > cacert.pem
```

Client /etc/openldap/ldap.conf contains:

```
BASE dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com
URI ldaps://10.42.0.1
TLS_CACERT    /etc/openldap/certs/cacert.pem
TLS_CIPHER_SUITE ALL:!NULL
```

(EDITS:)
Server /etc/openldap/slapd.conf:

```
include     /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema

TLSCACertificatePath    /etc/openldap/certs
TLSCertificateFile  Server-Cert
TLSCipherSuite        ALL:!NULL
TLSVerifyClient       never
disallow          bind_anon
#require              bind
#security         simple_bind=128

database    bdb
suffix      "dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=ldapadmin,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com"
rootpw      {SSHA}B1auWTJT2Prj9kOlci1vqALlROb48iBu
directory   /var/lib/ldap/xxxxxxx.com
pidfile     /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile    /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
cachesize   10000
checkpoint  128 15

database    config
rootdn      "cn=ldapadmin,cn=config"
rootpw      {SSHA}B1auWTJT2Prj9kOlci1vqALlROb48iBu
```

Comment: Something wrong with your *server*-side LDAP/TLS configuration. Post the relvant parts of `slapd.conf` or your online configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/5/slapd.conf) says:

> ## TLSCertificateKeyFile
>
> Specifies the file that contains the slapd server private key that matches the certificate stored in the TLSCertificateFile file. > Currently, the private key
>   must not be protected  with  a password, so it is of
>   critical importance that it is protected carefully.

I conclude that your private key file has a password. You need to change it so it doesn't.

(Apache HTTPD has a provision for handling this prompt, which I believe comes from the internals of OpenSSL. I've never found the equivalent in `slapd.conf`.)

It also says:

> ## TLSCertificatePath
>
> Specifies the path of a directory that contains Certificate Authority certificates in separate individual files. 
>   Usually only one of this or the TLSCACertificateFile is used.

Very strange configuration you have there.

Comment: thanks!  that was it!  Specifying the TLSCertificateKeyFile worked.  Though I still wonder where in the "certutil" commands above specified required that key password...

Comment: I use TLSCACertificate because in Redhat's portal, it says "When using Mozilla NSS with certificate and key database files specified with the olcTLSCACertificatePath directive, olcTLSCertificateFile is used to specify the name of the certificate to use."  Simply specifying TLSCertificatePath doesn't work.

Comment: But it's in the configuration you posted.

Comment: I mean, it seems I have to use the combination of TLSCACertificatePath and TLSCertificateFile; but not either one of these key words alone (I tried).

Comment: I have the same problem,I remove the pass from cert with openssl,but..ask for password on every run to unlock db of mozilla nss

Comment: @elbarna Then you didn't read my answer. I said to remove the password from the *private key file*. Not the certificate.